# Etimología de "nombre"

Tags: etimología, sustantivos, latín

Estoy intentando entender cómo se ha originado la palabra "nombre" a partir del latín, pero me resulta  difícil encontrar fuentes que la documenten. Únicamente he podido consultar la voz "nombre" del *Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico* de Coromines y Pascual. Se trata de un diccionario de 1980: me pregunto si ha habido avances posteriores sobre el tema.

Por lo que he leído, lo que está claro es que "nombre" deriva de un accusativo latino (como la mayoría de sustantivos de la lengua española). Según lo que explica el diccionario que he mencionado, este acusativo podría ser el correspondiente al latín clásico, NOMEN, pero también podría ser una forma del latín vulgar *NOMINE(M). Utilizo símbolos gráficos habituales: * para señalar que se se trata de una forma reconstruida y los paréntesis como indicación del hecho que la M final no se pronunciaba.

¿Se sabe hoy en día algo más sobre esta cuestión?

He visto también que el libro [*Romance Languages: A Historical Introduction*](https://books.google.es/books?id=9P3Ifze8gUQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22romance+languages:+a+historical+introduction%22&hl=it&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=%22NOMINE%20%27name%27%20....%20nombre%22&f=false) de Alkire y Rosen propone el latín NOMINE como origen del español "nombre". Da la impresión que el DOMINE del latín vulgar se ha podido documentar. ¿Es así?

Añado que en la evolución

> NOMINE > nombre

se producirían dos fenómenos habituales. El primero es la caída de la vocal átona postónica, fenómeno muy frecuente en palabras esdrújulas. El segundo es la inserción de una bilabial, la "b", entre la "m" (también bilabial) y la "n" para eliminar el contacto de dos consonantes nasales.

Comment: He encontrado un artículo publicado en el 2020  en el que aparece *NOMINE > nombre: https://scholar.google.es/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=es&user=zywtWdEAAAAJ&citation_for_view=zywtWdEAAAAJ:GnPB-g6toBAC.

Comment: Se puede descargar aquí: https://riuma.uma.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10630/19805/El%2520sustantivo-%2520evolucio%25CC%2581n%2520de%2520los%2520morfemas%2520de%2520caso%252C%2520ge%25CC%2581nero%2520y%2520nu%25CC%2581mero.pdf.

Comment: Veo que *NŌMINE(M) aparece en [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Latin/nominem), pero no tengo ni idea de cuál es la fuente.

Comment: Está en la RAE: nombre Del lat. nomen, -ĭnis. No veo el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Tradicionalmente se ha entendido que la palabra "nombre" procede del latín "nomen", aunque como curiosidad se encuentra la voz en francés "nombre" con el significado de "número" o la voz "nombril", también del francés, con el concepto de "ombligo".

La forma vulgar "Nomine", al igual que su evolución fonética, en el mismo caso que "homine" (hombre) y otras palabras con esta misma construcción, es la habitualmente señalada y origen de "nombre".

La voz "nomine" puedes encontrarla fácilmente en la Fórmula Trinitaria latina utilizada al bautizar o al hacer la señal de la cruz y hace referencia a cada una de las personas de la Santísima Trinidad (Padre, Hijo y Espíritu Santo),  "In **nomine** Patris et Filii et Spiritus Sancti", "En el **Nombre** del Padre, del Hijo y del Espíritu Santo".

En el caso de la voz "nombre" se habla de una disimilación del acusativo "nominem", por el que dos sonidos consonánticos muy similares, en este caso, "m y n" tienden a diferenciarse. Normalmente se da entre líquidas (r,l) y nasales (m,n), incluso la disimilación puede hacer desparecer una consonante.

Los pasos que se han sugerido para este proceso en el caso de la voz "nombre" han sido los siguientes;

- El acusativo en latín vulgar "nominem" pierde la vocal postónica y pasa a "nomne".
- Al estar las dos nasales (m,n) en contacto, la "n" sufre un proceso de disimilación convirtiéndose en "r", así "nomne" acabaría siendo "nomre" (nom - re, pronunciado como "arriba", ant. español también "ariba" u "honra" ant. español "onra" u "onrra"). En el S. XIII se podía encontrar las grafías r/rr para expresar el valor de vibrante múltiple en posición intervocálica.
- Entre la "m y r" de "nomre" aparece una epéntesis b, al entender que hay una restricción en la nasalización de "m" que al ser bilabial, deja ese rastro labial que recoge la "r", (pronúnciese repetidamente "nom - rre", para observar el efecto en el que aparece una especie de "b", "nombre"), produciéndose una labilidad sonora que pasa de "mr a mbr", por lo que "nomre", se convierte en "nombre". El mismo ejemplo es valido para la voz "hombro", del latín "humerus", en un proceso algo más corto que sirve de ayuda, así, tras la caída de la "e" aparece un elemento epentético "b", que contribuye a marcar el límite entre las dos sílabas (humerum > hom'ro > hombro).

---

**Similitud de las palabras "hombre" y "nombre" en su periodo evolutivo**.

*Fragmento del poema el "labrador avaro" de Gonzalo Berceo (1198 - 1264), de la obra Milagros de Nuestra Señora* *en versos monorrimos alejandrinos con rima consonante divididos en dos hemistiquios de siete sílabas separados por una cesura*.

El narrador cuenta la historia de un labrador que, a pesar de ser condenado al Infierno por su avaricia, es salvado por la Virgen gracias a su devoción mariana.

*La palabras* "***omne***" y "***nomne***" *se hallan en un intervalo de su proceso evolutivo* *hacia* "***hombre***" y "***nombre***".

> Era en una tierra un **omne** labrador
>
> que usava la reja más que otra lavor;
>
> más amava la tierra que non al Crïador,
>
> era de muchas guisas **omne** revolvedor.

...

> **Nomne** tan adonado e de vertut atanta,
>
> que a los enemigos seguda e espanta,
>
> non nos deve doler nin lengua nin garganta
>
> que non digamos todos: «Salve Regina Sancta.»

Comment: El ejemplo de NOMINE que das (Latín clásico totalmente estándar) es ablativo, no acusativo. Muchas gracias por tu contribución, pero no veo que tu respuesta añada información  significativa ni fuentes documentales a lo que he expuesto en la pregunta.

Comment: Añado que el francés "nombre" proviene de NUMĔRUS y no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: Lo siento, creía que estabas más especializada, "Introducción y aplicaciones contextualizadas a la lingüística hispánica Escrito por Manuel Diaz-Campos, Kimberly L. Geeslin, Laura Gurzynski-Weiss" o las "Actas III Congreso Hispánico de Latín Medieval: León, 26-29 de septiembre de 2002, Volumen 2", sobre el Latín Hispánico y que pueden ayudarte.  En cuanto a "Nombre" y "Nombril" en francés, se especifican que que son "número" y "ombligo", y por eso no dejan de ser simplemente una curiosidad gráfica, aunque obviamente, tengan en francés una procedencia distinta a la voz, "nombre", del español.